# How to merge multiple image files into one pdf file with page and its original size for every image?

Tags: pdf, pages, printing, image-editing

I have some images and I need to print it to ONE pdf file with size of pages as size of its images. How can I do that?

In other words I would like to achieve sth like this:

[image]

Read rectangle is a pdf file with 8 pages. Content of every page is an image.

Now what I have is pdf file with 8 pages scaled to white paper size A4 and then the image is centered within every white page.

Comment: is this on a Mac, what osx

Comment: the latest osx system

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

I found a tool that will do exactly what you want (one PDF, pages the size of images). You can find it at https://smallpdf.com/jpg-to-pdf. Upload your files, choose 'auto' as the size, choose 'no margin' as the margin and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Select and Open all images in Preview.

Select the File > Print dialog in Preview

[image: Preview Print dialog]

Set as showing, or modify to your desire.

Select "Save as PDF" (bottom left corner)

Result in PDF (I only used 2 images in this case) but you will have individual PDF pages for each.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a Quick Action (on Mojave) [here](https://github.com/benwiggy/PDFsuite/tree/master/Quick_Actions) that will Create a PDF from images, each one its own size, and not 'on a page'.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the app [PDFsam](https://pdfsam.org). This is a free, open source app. The "sam" in the name stands for "split and merge". This app is designed for what you have in mind. Depending on your requirements, you may have to move to an upgraded version which is not free.

Answer (score 0):

There are number of website that can be used to merge multiple images to one PDF files, some are free to use and some require subscription to avail their service. I currently use [PDFDoctor](https://pdfdoctor.com) to perform such operations.

Comment: Caveat emptor!  “Free” can cost much more than you think.  When you submit documents to a site like this, you give them access to ***everything*** on those documents (like personal information).  This is ripe for information harvesting and identity theft.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so using https://convertx2y.com/image-to-pdf/ This tool will merge any of your JPG and PNG images into a single PDF file. Plus, you can re-order the images before merging them into a PDF.